# Node.JS RequestError: No connection is specified for that request random error

Tags: node.js

I have the following code to perform a query on SQL server:

```
await sql.connect(process.env.DB_CSTRING)
let recordset = await sql.query(`select * FROM dbo.users WHERE (userId = ${userData.userId})
`)
    if (recordset.rowsAffected[0] > 0) {
        JsonResponse.success = 1
        JsonResponse.agentData = recordset.recordset[0]
    }
await sql.close();
```

So whille I was trying to call this API several times (by clicking on an angular app button constantly), I suddenly got the following error:

> Server running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/ (node:8180)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: No connection is
> specified for that request.

I fixed it with a try-catch as per the error message below, but even if the problem is fixed, I would like to learn why this is happening and if I am doing something wrong with the way Im performing the SQL connection and query:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> **without a catch block**, or **by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()**. To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 9)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a connection pool. One connection can't handle high loads (that you have simulated by pressing the button rapidly).

Comment: That means when I have several users connected, this will crash constantly? This is for an intranet with 50 users (insurance agents). The reason Im doing it that way, using sql.query is to sanitize the SQL string. I saw the connection pools but I understand I could not use the method Im using now and I have to use parameters. Is that correct? Thanks Max.

Comment: You are correct, it will crash constantly. IDK which library you use, so I can't help with that. About sanitation: the way you've written your query it's **not** sanitized. It is prone to injections. The way to sanitize is using the library api (parameterized query) - not embedding params directly in a query string...

Comment: Yes, it will crash, and yes, you are sanitizing by using sql.query. It wont if you open a connection and use conn.query, but sql.query does sanitize. You can also sanitize using a connection pool. Allow me a few minutes and I will explain you on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awaiting or .thening the pool creation is a safe way to ensure that the pool is always ready, without knowing where it is needed first. In practice, once the pool is created then there will be no delay for the next operation.

```
new sql.ConnectionPool(process.env.DB_CSTRING).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.query`select * FROM dbo.users WHERE (userId = ${userData.userId} `
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection.

Source:

https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#connection-pools

Comment: That's funny that you say it's auto sanitized. The lib creators contradict themselves in the same link you've posted: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#sql-injection
@Danielle I suggest you test this assumption before releasing to production.

Comment: That worked! But I have a question, let's say I need to do run another query below that one, should I do a new sql.ConnectionPool(process.env.DB_CSTRING).connect().then again? Will that affect performance?

Comment: MaxG, not really, they say "This module has built-in SQL injection protection. Always use parameters or tagged template literals to pass sanitized values to your queries" and what Im proposing Danielle is to use ES6 literal templates. It will work as long as she uses literals within SQL.query statement.

Comment: But you are right regarding the documentation and the information about ES6 is pretty ambiguous. The right thing to do is to try catch when using literals.